# How to convert XML string to XML file?

Tags: java, xml

I have a string in XML format. I need to convert that to an XML file. How would I do this?

Comment: You definitely need to provide more information.  Programming language or environment would be a good start.

Comment: its java,i just need to convert hte string that is having xml data to an xml file

Answer (score 10):

Java:

```
XMLDoc=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<root><main>Title</main></root&g t;")));
```

If you use C#, try this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XDoc.LoadXml("<Root><body>hello</body></Root>");

    XDoc.Save(@"D:\Temp\MyXMl.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a string which contains XML? Then just write it to a file. In Java? A FileWriter should work just fine.

Comment: It's not that easy. The character encoding must be determined from the document header if present, otherwise UTF-8 must be chosen. Simply using a FileWriter and the platform's default encoding is in most situations wrong.

Comment: That's true, I was assuming that it wouldn't have a prolog. If it doesn't, then you would have to use a writer using UTF-8 or UTF-16 as its encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Use XStream library it is quite simple:
http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

```
                // object -> XML -> File 
    XStream xstream = new XStream(driver);
    String data = xstream.toXML(metaData);

                //  XML -> object
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    YourClass obj = (UourClass)xstream.fromXML(jSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the string to a file with .xml extension.Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
class writeXML {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            String s="<xmltag atr=value>tag data</xmltag>";
            FileWriter fr= new FileWriter(new File("a.txt"));
            Writer br= new BufferedWriter(fr);
            br.write(s);
            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```